# Are packages deleted when upgrading R on Linux?

Tags: r, linux

**Are packages deleted when upgrading R on Linux?** I would prefer to just use the default package installation directory, instead of setting up a custom directory.

I'm aware I can setup a custom directory in the following manner:

```
cat >> ~/.Renviron
R_LIBS=/data/Rpackages/
```

I just wonder what happens if I don't issue the command above? Will packages be wiped every time I issue the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

, and as a consequence R gets updated to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

@Jason, when you are doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, it just upgrade packages that have a new version in your list of repositories. There is no reason it will modify R packages already installed.

I'm also running Linux and R and the only time I have to re-install R packages is when I re-install my system. My R packages are installed by default in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`

Comment: I didn't know that. I was under the assumption that `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` would upgrade my specific `r-base` or `r-base-dev` installations, and I would need to issue some type of command in R, such as `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` to update the packages.

Comment: On my OS, even when I upgrade `r-base` or `r-base-dev`, it does not change anything on other R packages. I assume that is modifying only what need to be modified.